# Problem regarding non-mathematical objects being sets themselves

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In pure set theory 1 is also a set but do we also conclude non-mathematical objects to be sets themselves.

Comment: What do you mean by a non-mathematical object?

Comment: like any physical object

Comment: I don't think anyone is claiming that, say, an apple is a set. There is no claim that physical objects are sets.

Comment: No mathematical object is 'physical' and no mathematical theory gives any information about 'the real world'

Comment: In a pure set theory such as ZFC, everything is a set. More general set theories allow for the presence of non-sets, called [urelements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urelement). Alternatively, if the axiom of foundation is dropped, a physical object may be regarded as a [Quine atom](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/quine/), i.e., a set $a$ such that $\{a\}=a$. In other words, the symbol $x\in a$ is interpreted to mean that $x$ is an element of $a$ if $a$ is a set, or $x=a$ if $a$ is a physical object.

Comment: Tao deals with analysis and the mathematical objects of his theory are : numbers and functions. In addition, he consider sets : sets are sets of numbers, sets of functions and sets of sets, being set also objects. Conclusion : in Tao's book there are **no** non-mathematical objects.

Comment: In "pure" set theory **every** mathematical object is built-up from sets. Thus, numbers are no more "specific" objects but are set themselves. But set th is a mathematical theory, and thus it does not aim at building non-Mathematical objects (like e.g. humans or books).

Answer (score 3):

### How to interpret what Set Theorists mean by the word "*set*":

Set Theory is a field of logic that was developed in a hopeful way to describe all of mathematics in terms of formal logic. It got off to a great start, until Gödel proved that the whole endeavour is impossible with his incompleteness theorem. Regardless of that, it turned out that the developed theory is still a very powerful tool to think about *most of mathematics*

Most commonly, we associate with set theory the theory of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, or Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory with choice. To describe this theory, we use the language of first-order logic (basically the operators $\land, \lor, \lnot, \to, \forall$ and $\exists$, the equality symbol $=$ and some variables $x,y,\dots$), with as additional symbol "$\in$", which we will use to describe set membership.

Now what do we mean by **theory**: a theory is nothing more than a set of axioms, written in a logical language. Examples of such axioms are the *Axiom of Extensionality*:

$$
\forall x\forall y\forall z((x\in y\leftrightarrow x\in z)\to y=z)
$$
which says that if we have two *things* $y$ and $z$ and all elements of $y$ are elements of $z$ and vice versa, then $y$ and $z$ are the same *thing*, or the *Axiom of Empty set*:
$$
\exists x\forall y(y\notin x)
$$
which describes a *thing* that does not have any elements, and we usually denote this by the symbol $\varnothing$.

Now the question is of course, what are these "*things*"? In a certain way, these axioms do not have a meaning until we interpret them. This is where **models** come into play. A model is nothing more than some *things* such that all the non-logical symbols in our language (in this case "$\in$") can be interpreted in the model such that all the axioms in our theory become true.

We decide to call these "*things*" in our model "*sets"*. **That** is what a set is: the objects of a model of set theory. The class of all the things in our model is what we call the "*universe*", and anything that is not *inside* the universe is considered not a set. This (usually) excludes all the physical objects from being sets (depending on if you imagine a model that contains physical objects or not).

There is a slight issue with *models* of Set Theory, namely that we have no way of constructing them using just the axioms of Set Theory, as we cannot prove that the axioms are consistent (this is the problematic result that Gödel proved). But this doesn't mean we cannot imagine what a model would look like, and get a natural feel for what the objects of such a model, namely *sets*, are.

---

As a comparison, think of Group Theory. We can also describe an axiomatic system for Group Theory (which is how one usually learns it). A model for these axioms is then a *group*. There are wildly different interpretations for what the elements of such a group can be. They could be integers, or they could be permutations, or they could be matrices, etc.

The thing to understand here is that it is dependent on the *model* how we consider  these objects in our universe to look like.